# Is there a way to automatically close Messages when I start a screen share in Zoom?

Tags: messages, zoom.app

Not kill the notifications, but close the whole app. I'm tired of sharing my screen in meetings and forgetting that I had sent my spouse a text saying "look how much the dog pooped" or "I just spent the entire work day looking at baby orangutan videos."

Comment: I always say - “Modify your behavior, not the OS.”